# New tag regarding music/theme songs/anthems

Tags: feature-request, tags

When asking [this question](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/9188/ibu-biathlon-theme), I wanted to put a music related tag on it, which did not yet exist. Since there is quite some sport-related music out, it might be helpful to do so. So, my question is: do we need such a tag?

Whether it is named [anthem](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4489/what-anthem-does-the-west-indies-cricket-team-use), [theme song](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/4469/which-song-was-played-before-the-national-anthem-in-the-world-t20-2014-in-bangla/4954#4954), music (might be most general) or something else, might be a secondary question.

Answer (score 2):

We have the [media](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/media) tag. This should cover what you are looking for.